# Fetch comments for a Status Update in LinkedIn

Tags: php, linkedin-api

I am authenticating myself in LinkedIn and able to fetch the company page status updates using the following URL and get correct result.
.........../2414183/updates?format=json

But when I try to fetch the comments for a specific company update, using [this URL](https://api.linkedin.com/v1/companies/2414183/updates/key=UPDATE-c2414183-5991757589652725760/update-comments?format=json), I get a NULL response. But there are 2 comments for the same.

Doing everything according to [this](https://developer.linkedin.com/docs/company-pages). I'm not able to figure it, what is wrong in the statement or the reason for not getting the comments?

Comment: **"message": "Unknown authentication scheme",** ??

Comment: No, I am authenticated. Cause am able to pull the status updates from the company pages.